# Outlook 2013 Automatically Moving Conversation From Folder To Inbox

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, outlook.com

I get over 100 emails a day with different requests and I am trying to keep organized with inbox 0.
I have a few folders like "Needs Attention", "Waiting", "Archived". I also changed my "View" setting to "Show as Conversation".

What I am trying to do is when an email comes in and I cannot get to it right that second I put it in "Needs Attention". Or, If I have sent out something and I am waiting for a response I put it in "Waiting".

However, when someone responds it seems to start a new conversation in my Inbox and I need to go through my 2 filter folders and move everything to Archived once completed.

Any way to have the whole conversation move back to my Inbox for review?

I would even be OK if the conversation continued in the folder I put it in. Maybe a different suggestion?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/outlook-2013-apply-conversation-settings-to-all/7c1470db-bea3-4ebd-8532-27054cf6512c) help here?

Comment: I am sorry, I totally missed this. I tried it out but I think I already did this one by one a different way. I will report back later if anything changed.

Comment: So I Just got an email that I had moved to my Archived folder. The original email Conversation is in Archived with the last email being from 11:46 while my inbox does not not show in Conversation View and newest email is from 12:32. 

I Either want the whole conversation to move back to the Inbox (No longer in my Sub Folder) or the Email Conversation (Chain) to be continued in the sub folder.

Answer (score -1):

Conversation view is a view setting which only be applied to emails in one folder. It won’t move subsequent emails to one conversation together.

Considering your situation, you can create a rule to move specific emails to specific sub-folder.
Or, move the whole conversation when all the responses have been received.

Check [this link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/94b81566-b523-4235-8563-c90bac2e5203/shared-mailbox-folders-and-grouped-conversation?forum=outlook)